# Archiving xcode project that contains static library

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, static-libraries, archiving

I created a project with static library.
When I tried to archive, It fails and library Headers are missing.
But when I build the app, it works fine.

And in build folder headers, bundle resources and library are created outside app file.
Is it possible to create these file in app file and archive
or any other process available for archiving?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It fails" - describe exactly how.

Comment: Header files are missing when archiving

Comment: What I do with project with static libraries is create an include folder, with sybolic links (ln -s origin destination) to the headers files, and add the path of the include folder to the main project "Headers Search Path", so you don't need to mantain any script or anything else to copy the headers files, and the linked headers will change as the origin change

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru did you find why I was stuck on same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to build the app but not archive then it seems that the build settings that you are using for archive build configuration (probably Release) is not correct. Quick test will be to change the  build configuration for archive to same as build, most probably Debug  (you can do that in Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme).

To fix this you can open the Build Settings for your target, search for "Header Search Path", click the ">" to open this setting and fix it for the build configuration that is used by archive (i.e. make it same as the build configuration used by Build)